# Add Item To ObservableArray() And Wait Until It's Added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have a VM with the following:

```
var myArray = ko.observableArray(),
....
addItem = function(data) {
    myArray.unshift(data);
},
```

In my View I have some HTML that binds to it:

```
   <div data-bind="foreach: myArray">
   ....<label data-bind:="attr: { id: 'myLabel_' + name }"></Label>
   </div>
```

Everything works great - when I call the addItem function an item gets added to my obserableArray() and Knockout adds the appropriate HTML.

The problem I'm facing now is when, instead of just using plain HTML, I try to use a more complex control (like a Kendo grid).  I need to call a Javascript method to initiate the Grid when I call newItem.  But if I do that, it doesn't work (I assume because Knockout hasn't 'finished' doing what it does, when the Kendo control tries to do what it needs to do).

The following doesn't work:

```
var myArray = ko.observableArray(),
....
addItem = function(data) {
    myArray.unshift(data);
    var test = $('#myLabel_nameOne');
    // Kendo specific code to setup test
},
```

If I run the same Kendo specific code from the console - it works great.  If I use a setInterval, that will work too.

I know there is an 'afterRender' I can hook into on an entire template - but I'm just looking to know when the UI is done after adding a single item into that observableArray.

What's the proper way to say 'Wait until this is really added, then go do this other stuff?'  Or 'Add this, and when the UI is ready, call this function for me'?

Comment: It feels like you have an XY-problem. The actual problem we can't quite help with because you've simplified a bit too much (we need a repro for that), and the question you end up asking is really vague without more context.

Comment: It's all in the [docs...](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements)

Answer (score 1):

I've hit asynchronous issues with frameworks other than Knockout and usually solved them by writing wrappers with jQuery and the Deferred() object.

After reading Knockout documentation you can just use the subscribe function.

```js
var myArray = ko.observableArray()
myArray.subscribe(function(data) {
  var test = $('#myLabel' + data.name);
  // Kendo specific code to setup test
});
  ....
addItem = function(data) {
  myArray.unshift(data);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Oddly enough, this works great in Chrome and Firefox, but does not work in IE.  I'll update my question to include code that reproduces my issue.

Comment: Hmmm that seems a bit strange. Add a console debug right after unshift and a second one inside your subscribe function to check order of execution.